# Using server side code in a Windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, windows-8

For writing Windows 8 apps in JS/HTML5, is there any way to incorporate server side code? Like, for example, I have an asp.net web app with C# on the back end. What would be the easiest way of porting it to a Windows Store app?

thanks,

Amanda

Answer (score 0):

If you have a C# ASP.NET application that you are porting to Win8 JavaScript / HTML5 there is no real scope for porting code. Your best bet is to port design (both graphical and functional) rather than implementation.